# Split dataset by every other day

Tags: pandas

I have a dataset that I collected over many days and is indexed by calendar day. Each day has a different number of entries in it. I want to see if the odd days (e.g. day 1, day 3, day 5, etc...) are correlated with the even days (e.g. day 2, day 4, day 6 etc...) and to do this, I have to split my dataset into two.

I can't use day % 2 because I have missing days and weekends in the set that throw it off. I have tried using resample like this:

```
df_odd = df.resample('2D') 
lowest_date = df['date_minus_time'].min() 
df_even = df.query('date_minus_time != @lowest_date).resample('2D')
```

But this insists on aggregating the data by day. I want to keep all the rows so I can perform further operations (e.g. groupby) on the resulting datasets.

How can I create two dataframes, one with all the rows with an "even" date and one with all the rows with an "odd" date with even and odd being relative to first day of my data set?

Here are some example data:

```
Date          var
2018-12-10    1
2018-12-10    0
2018-12-10    1
2018-12-10    0
2018-12-11    1
2018-12-11    1
2018-12-12    0
2018-12-12    1
2018-12-12    1
2018-12-14    1
2018-12-14    0
2018-12-14    1
2018-12-16    1
2018-12-16    1
2018-12-16    1
```

And the expected output:

df_odd:

```
Date          var
2018-12-10    1
2018-12-10    0
2018-12-10    1
2018-12-10    0
2018-12-12    0
2018-12-12    1
2018-12-12    1
2018-12-16    1
2018-12-16    1
2018-12-16    1
```

df_even:

```
Date          var
2018-12-11    1
2018-12-11    1
2018-12-14    1
2018-12-14    0
2018-12-14    1
```

Comment: you can access the day by `df.date_minus_time.day.dt.day` which gives you the actual day number (eg. `Feb 21 2019 -> 21, Mar 13 1985-> 13`). I'm not sure that's what you want though.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and expected output?

Comment: @run-out I have added an example. Quang-Hoang, I can't use that because  I want half the data to end up in one and half in the other.  In the example I posted using actual day would give me one data frame with Dec 10, 12, 14, 16 and the other with Dec 11 only.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.Categorical` with `.codes`

```
num = pd.Categorical(df.Date).codes + 1
df_odd = df[num%2 == 0]
df_even = df[num%2 == 1]

df_odd

          Date  var
0   2018-12-10    1
1   2018-12-10    0
2   2018-12-10    1
3   2018-12-10    0
6   2018-12-12    0
7   2018-12-12    1
8   2018-12-12    1
12  2018-12-16    1
13  2018-12-16    1
14  2018-12-16    1

df_even

          Date  var
4   2018-12-11    1
5   2018-12-11    1
9   2018-12-14    1
10  2018-12-14    0
11  2018-12-14    1
```